# A non-metrizable, topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My question is about an example of a non-metrizable, topological space that I don't really understand. My text defines a set $X=\{0,1\}$ with the topology $T_{X}=\{\emptyset,X,\{0\}\}$. And, as a proof of what I've said, it says that $\{0\}$ is an open, compact and not closed set (I understand this).

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Ok I see the context. What's the question though?

Comment: There is also another explanation: $X$ is not Hausdorff (as $0$ and $1$ can't be seperated by disjoint open sets as the smallest open set containing $1$ is already $X$), but metrizable spaces have to be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $X$ your text is referencing is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) (from now on, I'll refer to $X$ as $S$). As you correctly pointed out, $\{0\}$ is not closed. If $S$ were metrizable by some metric, say $d$, then $$\{0\}=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\{x\in S\mid d(0,x)\leq \varepsilon\}$$
would be closed (since each $\{x\in S\mid d(0,x)\leq \varepsilon\}$ is closed, since $x\mapsto d(0,x)$ is continuous).

An alternative way of looking at what I just did is that every metric space is Hausdorff and in a Hausdorff every singleton is closed (and $\{0\}$ isn't) so $S$ mustn't be metric.

A last way of looking at it is that on a metric, every compact is closed, $\{0\}$ is compact but not closed, $S$ must not be metric.